# localhost exhibiting weird behavior

Tags: webserver, localhost

So right now I am trying to open a folder on my local host and cannot because every time I try to access localhost/myfolder I get a you don't have permissions error. I tried copying and pasting this said folder to Library/WebServer/Documents and the even weirder thing is that other folder I copy do show up in localhost but this one does not. All this folder has is some html in it. Does anybody have any idea why this could be happening? Thanks!

Comment: If your server is on Linux, make sure the web server has read privileges. Otherwise set permissions to 777 to see if the issue lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not have permissions to read the document.

Try:

chmod -R 755 Library/WebServer/Documents

This will give read/write/execute permissions to the user. read/write to the group and read/write to other. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod for more info on chmod.